# Convert a list into multiple data frame by list column

Tags: r, list, function, dataframe

I have import a excel file with multi worksheets. It’s a list format.

```
names(mysheets)
#[1] "test_sheet1" "test_sheet2"
```

Test_sheet1 and test _sheet2 have a different matrix.

I have to put each worksheets as individual data frame.

If do it manually, the code will look like this:

```
s_1 <- data.frame(mysheets[1])
s_2 <- data.frame(mysheets[2])
```

I try to write a function to do it, because I have many excel files and each file have multi worksheets

#### function

```
p_fun <- function (y) {
for (s_i in 1:2) {
  for (i in 1:2) {
    s_i<- data.frame(y[i])
      return(s_i) }}}
```

It didn’t work correctly. 
Appreciate if anyone can help.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `mget` to get the object and then change them to data.frame

```
list_df <- lapply(mget(names(mysheets)), data.frame)
```

If you want them as separate dataframes, we can do

```
names(list_df) <- paste0('s_', seq_along(list_df))
list2env(list_df, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Hi, the first line using mget, I have received this error 'Error in mget(mysheets) : invalid first argument'.

Comment: @user3624948 Do you need `list_df <- lapply(names(mysheets), data.frame)` ?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `assign` if we are doing this in a `for` loop

```
for(i in seq_along(mysheets)) assign(paste0("s", i), data.frame(mysheets[i]))
```